# Build universal binary (Apple Silicon & Intel) in GUI of Xcode without make file?

Tags: xcode, macos, universal-binary

For a long time I'm using Xcode and compile my project using Product/Build command. Then I find the compiled app when right click on "Products" files. So I can get it from there and copy it to where ever I want.

But how to create a universal binary with Apple Silicon & Intel without using a make file? On my M1 MBP it creates only for itself. My Mac Mini with INTEL inside wont run that app.  I'm compiling it on my Mac Mini as well to get a version which runs there too.
Any hints? (maybe with some screenshots)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! In the top line right of the stop button you can choose the build option getting a universal binary. Seems to be a new option I didn't found till now.